# How to show files by extension in NERDTree?

Tags: vim, file-type, nerdtree

[How to filter out files by extension in NERDTree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5601749/how-to-filter-out-files-by-extension-in-nerdtree) shows filtering **OUT** files by extension, but I'd like to filter **IN** files by extension. Is there any way to show only specific extensions and folders in NERDTree?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
let NERDTreeIgnore=['\(.txt\|.md\)\@<!$[[file]]']
```

This will ignore all files that don't end in `.txt` OR (`\|`) `.md`.

It matches the atom `.txt` OR `.md` and then uses the `\@<!` operand (see `:help \@<!`) to match if the preceding atom does NOT match just before `$` (the end of the line). The `[[file]]` at the end is NERDTree internals that specifies files instead of directories. If you don't use this directories that don't end in that file extension will be ignored too.

Comment: So for multiple extensions I just need to add multiple lines of the similar code, and directories that don't have those filetypes will be ignored in the tree? Thanks!

Comment: You can use the `\|` operator within the selection atom as shown in the edit above. Please upvote or accept answer if it helps.