# How to ignore certain folders when recursively opening files in NERDTree

Tags: vim, nerdtree

For example, I'd like to ignore opening `node_modules` since opening it will only muddy my view of the project. How can I ignore that but recursively open everything else?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to filter out files by extension in NERDTree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5601749/how-to-filter-out-files-by-extension-in-nerdtree)

Comment: Additionally, [this](https://github.com/preservim/nerdtree/issues/817) might also help.
`let g:NERDTreeIgnore = ['^node_modules$']`